# CHIRPS GEF Download with R

Tags: raster, r, download, climate, precipitation

I need to download CHIRPS-GEF (rainfall forecast) raster data in R. I have tried with

```
url <- "https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-GEFS_precip_v12/daily_16day/2023/10/17/*.tif"
file_name <- "*.tif"
file_path <- "C:/......./_GEF_FORE/down/"
download.file(url, paste(file_path, file_name, sep = ""),  mode = "wb")
```

But it does not work
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "*" in a URL and expect the server to return all matches. Requests using `download.file` can only get one thing at a time, usually.

Looking at the index page, and guessing, I suspect each folder has 16 days of forecast starting on the day in the URL:

https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-GEFS_precip_v12/daily_16day/2023/10/17/

So for any given day you need to work out the URLs for the 16 days in question.

```
now = as.Date("2023-10-17")
root = paste0("https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-GEFS_precip_v12/daily_16day/",format(now,"%Y/%m/%d"))

filename = function(d){paste0("data.",format(d,"%Y.%m%d"),".tif")}
```

Then to download the 16 days of forecast TIFFs:

```
for(d in now:(now+15)){
 dd = as.Date(d)
 path = paste0(root, "/",filename(dd))
 download.file(path, destfile=filename(dd))
}
```

This would be neatest wrapped into a function:

```r
get_daily = function(now){
    root = paste0("https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-GEFS_precip_v12/daily_16day/",format(now,"%Y/%m/%d"))
    filename = function(d){paste0("data.",format(d,"%Y.%m%d"),".tif")}
    for(d in now:(now+15)){
     dd = as.Date(d)
     path = paste0(root, "/",filename(dd))
     download.file(path, destfile=filename(dd))
    }
}
```

Then you can run it for any given date via `get_daily(as.Date("2023-10-17"))`